# Searching more than one column using PHP for getting json data

Tags: php, json, angularjs

Following code works fine to search film by filmName but i want to add some more feature such as search film by year and by actor. Since I am using Angular JS its being bit tough

My requirement is to use more advance search such as filmbyyear and by Actor Name how i can integrate the same using above code such as:

search films by     `filmName LIKE '%$filmName%' AND '%$filmYear%' AND '%$filmActor%'`

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

$key =  $objData->data;
if(!empty($key)){

    $sql = "SELECT filmName as film, url as param, imagePath as image FROM films WHERE filmName LIKE '%$key%' LIMIT 5";

    $result =   mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $output = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;

    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: what is your json data ?

Comment: @ Murtaza this is the json data {"movie":[{"film":"Besharam","param":"besharam-film-2013.html","filmYear":"2013","filmActor":"Ranbir Kapoor, Pallavi Sharda, Rishi Kapoor, Neetu Singh, Javed Jaffrey, Amitosh Nagpal, Kamal Kiri, Kunal Agrawal, Mohan Kapoor, Remo d'souza, Vishal Singh"}]}

Answer (score 0):

As per your data, you need to decode it

```
{"movie":[{"film":"Besharam","param":"besharam-film-2013.html","filmYear":"2013"‌​,"filmActor":"Ranbir Kapoor, Pallavi Sharda, Rishi Kapoor, Neetu Singh, Javed Jaffrey, Amitosh Nagpal, Kamal Kiri, Kunal Agrawal, Mohan Kapoor, Remo d'souza, Vishal Singh"}]}

$data = json_decode($json);
$file = $data->movie[0]->film;
$fileYear = $data->movie[0]->filmYear;
```

Comment: how i can use the same in my code above, please suggest it as i am beginner in php as if you see my code the json is generated dynamically so need help in integrating with $objData = json_decode($data);

$key =  $objData->data;
if(!empty($key)){

Comment: what do mean by that ?